# Help me with this linear algebra problem, please.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

For wich values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ does the matrix $A$ is diagonalizable: $$A=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1+\alpha & -\alpha & \alpha \\ 2+\alpha & -\alpha & \alpha-1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

I obtained this caracteristic polynomtal $$ -\lambda ^3 + \lambda ^2+ \lambda -1$$ and the eigenvalues are $$\lambda=1$$ and $$\lambda=-1$$
The eigenvectors are $N(A+I)=(0,0,1)^T$ and $N(A-I)=(2,3,1)^T$.
Sorry for the misunderstands, I'm new here

Comment: Did you try to calculate the characteristic polynomial ?

Comment: Yes I did, in fact I also calculated the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors, but I didn't know how to proceed

Comment: You should share more thought on what you have done. It would be beneficial for all if you edit the post and explain what you have calculated and what the eigenvalues are. If your eigenvalues are correct it will be much easier to proceed, the eigenvalues are very simple here.

Comment: I just made the changes.

Comment: Hence, $\lambda=-1$ has multiplicity $1$ and $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity $2$. A possible trouble for diagonalization comes from the latter. Now you need to look at how the Jordan block for $\lambda=1$ may look like. Is it one block $2\times 2$ (then not-diagonalizable) or two scalar blocks (then diagonalizable).

Comment: Shouldn't your characteristic polynomial (and hence your eigenvalues) depend on $\alpha$?

Comment: I got the same polynomial as you. For $\lambda = -1$, I found $(0,1,1)^T$. For $\lambda = 1$ and $\alpha \ne 0$, I got $(2,3,1)^T$ as you. I am blocked too

Answer (score 1):

$$A=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1+\alpha & -\alpha & \alpha \\ 2+\alpha & -\alpha & \alpha-1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

$$A - \lambda I=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1+\alpha -\lambda& -\alpha & \alpha \\ 2+\alpha & -\alpha - \lambda & \alpha-1 \\ 2 & -1 & -\lambda \end{array} \right)$$

The characteristic polynomial is $$ -\lambda^3+\lambda^2+\lambda -1 = -(\lambda + 1)(\lambda-1)^2.$$

And the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $ \lambda_2 = -1$

$$A - I=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \alpha & -\alpha & \alpha \\ 2+\alpha & -\alpha - 1 & \alpha-1 \\ 2 & -1 & -1 \end{array} \right).$$

The corresponding eigenspace $ V_1 = \ker(A- I) = \{v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3: (A-I)v = 0 \}$ is

1. if $\alpha = 0$ : 
   $$ \ker(A- I) = \{ (v_1,2v_1 - v_3,v_3) \vert v_1,v_3 \in \mathbb{R}\} = < (1,2,0) \; (0,-1,1)> $$
2. if $\alpha\neq 0:$

$$ \ker(A- I) = \{ (2v_3,3v_3,v_3) \vert v_3 \in \mathbb{R}\} = <(2,3,1)>$$

$$A + I=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 2 + \alpha & -\alpha & \alpha \\ 2+\alpha & -\alpha +1 & \alpha-1 \\ 2 & -1 & 1 \end{array} \right).$$

The corresponding eigenspace $ V_2 = \ker(A + I) = \{v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3: (A+I)v = 0 \}$ is

1. if $\alpha = 0$:

$$ \ker(A+ I) = \{ (0,v_2,v_2) \vert v_2 \in \mathbb{R}\} = <(0,1,1)> .$$

2. if $\alpha \neq 0$:

$$ \ker(A+ I) = \{ (0,v_2,v_2) \vert v_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

If $ \alpha = 0$ then we have a basis of eigenvectors and A is diagonalisable if $\alpha \neq 0$ then $A$ is not diagonalisable.

Comment: This is the result OP and I arrived, see the comments. The issue is to explain why for $\alpha \ne 0$, we can get two eigenvectors and three real eigenvalues ...

Comment: Which 3 real eigenvalues ? $1$ and $-1$ are the only real roots of the characteristic polynomial

Comment: $\lambda = 1$ has a multipllcity of 2. But I may miss something effectively

Comment: All you need for diagonalisation is a basis of eigenvectors. In the case $\alpha \neq 0$ you cannot construct such a base because the eigenvectors can't possibly span $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let's try to construct a basis explicitly. Take $v \neq 0$ an eigenvector. Then $v \in V_1 $ or $v \in V_2$. Without loss of generality take $v \in V_1$. Take $v'$ an eigenvector that is linearly independent of $v$. Then $v' \not \in V_1$ since $V_1$ is one dimensional. Therefore $v' \in V_2$. Notice that since $V_1$ and $V_2$ are one dimensional you can't find  $v'' \not \in span (v,v')$

Comment: I understand that. My concern was the multiplicity of $\lambda = 1$. I was thinking that a relationship exists between this multiplicity and the dimension of the corresponding subset. This is why I was blocked. But it is clear that  I was wrong. I will have to refresh my knowledge on that. Thank you